# How do I set multiple paths in prosody's ldap basedn variable

Tags: lua, ldap, jitsi-meet, prosody-im

I've set up a jitsi-meet instance for test purposes and I use the ldap-related modules for user authentication configured in `/etc/prosody/conf.d/ldap.cfn.lua`. Here is my working `ldap.cfn.lua` (I removed usernames and passwords and replaced them with *):

```
-- Authentication configuration --

authentication = 'ldap2'

ldap = {
    hostname      = 'my.ldap.server.org',
    --use_tls     = true,
    bind_dn       = 'CN=ldap,OU=user,OU=my,DC=company,DC=org',
    bind_password = '***', 

    user = {
      basedn        = 'ou=workers,ou=location1,dc=my,dc=company,dc=org',
      filter        = 'sAMAccountName=*',
      usernamefield = 'sAMAccountName',
      namefield     = 'cn',
    },
}
```

I have several locations within my AD (evolved historically) and I need to query them too. How can I specify more than one `basedn` parameter? Here is what I tried so far without positive results (mere guesses).

```
user = {
      basedn        = 'ou=workers,ou=location1,dc=my,dc=company,dc=org',
                      'ou=workers,ou=location2,dc=my,dc=company,dc=org',
      filter        = ...
      ...
},
```

```
user = {
      basedn        = '(ou=workers,ou=location1,dc=my,dc=company,dc=org,ou=workers,ou=location2,dc=my,dc=company,dc=org)',
      filter        = ...
      ...
},
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily I've figered out another solution in the meantime:

In my case it's not neccessary to query multiple OU within the AD. It's sufficient to query the very root of my AD and filter for every `Domain User`.

This site gave valuable hints: https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Domain%20Users

Here is my working config:

```
authentication = 'ldap2'

ldap = {
    hostname      = 'my.ldap.server.org',
    --use_tls     = true,
    bind_dn       = 'CN=ldap,OU=user,OU=my,DC=company,DC=org',
    bind_password = '***', 

    user = {
      basedn        = 'dc=my,dc=company,dc=org',
      filter        = '(primaryGroupID=513)',
      usernamefield = 'sAMAccountName',
      namefield     = 'cn',
    },
}
```